# Declaring a 2D array of type struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct, multidimensional-array

I declared a struct which is supposed to be a pixel and it has 3 properties (`x`, `y` location and `F` intensity) like this:

```
struct pixel {
    int F,          // intensity from 0-255
    x,              // horizontal component           
    y;              // vertical component
};
```

Then I declared an 2D array of type pixel (the struct above) like this:

```
int N=100;
pixel image[N][N];
```

Then I used the following loop to assign values to `x` and `y`:

```
int count, k;

for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    for (int j=0 ; j<N ; j++)
    {
        k = j + i*N;
        image.x[k] = count;
        count++; 
     }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What sort of problem are you seeing?

Comment: The count variable is not initialized. It can be just about anything at first (undefined value), then you're simply incrementing that undefined value. You can't expect variables to be automatically initialized to 0.

Comment: Welcome to SO, posting your code as you did is very helpful but always try to explain the problem you are having as well...what is/isn't working correctly and how, what errors you may be getting, etc...

Comment: Thank u!!
and sorry for not being explicite

Comment: i understood what was wrong from the answers below thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
image.x[k] = count;
```

is incorrect. You declared a 2D array of pixels:

```
pixel image[N][N];
```

The way to access an element of the array is as follows:

```
image[i][j].x = count;
```

You do not need to calculate the flat index k yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `i` and `j` to index into `image`:

```
    image[i][j].x = count;
```

I don't see why you'd need `k` and the explicit index calculation at all. The compiler will do it for you automatically.

Comment: ok i got it thanks :)
however, i do need to calculate k if i was using a dynamic 2D-array right??

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to index a field of the struct rather than the struct itself, plus you are not indexing it as a 2D array.

Rather than doing:

```
image.x[k]
```

Do:

```
image[i][j].x
```

Also, does your code compile?  Some compilers will reject an declaration of an array where the bounds are variables, even if const.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'k' is not defined. So, it will use a garbage value for k.

Also, for indexing of a point in an image, you have to use:

```
image[i][j]
```

So, the correction in your program will be:

```
image[i][j].x = count;
```

instead of `image.x[k] = count;`