# 2D array of structures with new keyword in C++!

Tags: c++, structure, multidimensional-array

I have a structure defined in a file called 'xxx.h':

```
struct struct_name
{
   declarations;
};
```

I included this header - 'xxx.h' - in another c++ file, yyy.cpp

And then I try to create a 2D array of the above structure using new keyword  as follows (I learnt how to create a 2D array of structures from this link: [Declaring a 2D array of type struct in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847980/declaring-a-2d-array-of-type-struct-in-c)).

```
struct struct_name * some_name;
some_name = new struct struct_name[x][y];
```

When I compile, I get the following error: `error: ‘y’ cannot appear in a constant-expression`. This error particularly points to the second dimension of the array.

Also When I tried to initialize this 2D array of structures with some value like:

```
some_name[i][j].var_name = value;
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(some_name + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)i) * 12u)))[j]’
```

Please advise me how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interest of getting you up and running as quickly as possible, I'm going to belay the usual memory layout diatribe and simply tell you one way to get your situation resolved.

The reason you're error is happening is because C++ requires knowledge of *types* when declaring an array, allocating an array, etc. When you do this:

```
some_name = new struct_name[x][y];
```

what you're telling the compiler is "I want to allocate `x` objects of type `struct_name[y]`". But `struct_name[y]` isn't a *type* known at compile-time. The size is unknown, but must be known (thus the error about a `constexpr` expectations. This would work:

```
struct_name (*some_name)[WIDTH] = new struct_name[x][WIDTH];
```

would work if `WIDTH` is a compile-time known-constant. But for you, that isn't constant so another solution is required.

---

**Altnerative Approach**

An alternative quick-fix approach is presented below

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int rows, cols;

    // get row and column count.

    typedef std::vector<struct_name> MatrixRow;
    typedef std::vector<MatrixRow> Matrix;
    Matrix some_name(rows, MatrixRow(cols));

    // use some_name[i][j] however you need

    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is likely the *fastest* way to get you running. Further, it promotes proper [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) concepts. If you need a more specialized purpose of a 2D matrix you may have to develop your own class, as the C++ standard library has no direct 2D dynamic array concept natively, thus why we invent it using a vector of vector-types.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thanks so much WhozCraig. Your alternative approach worked :-)  I used alternative approach because WIDTH is input only during runtime.

Comment: @Casey thanks for the fix. much apprec the correction. was On my way! to go xmas shopping and in a bit of a hurry. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the declaration within yyy.cpp as:

```
struct struct_name **some_name;
```

The reason for this is that `some_name[i]` needs to be of type `struct_name *` in order to access another level of variables.

Comment: Note: a dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays is NOT the same as a genuine 2D array. Both the types and the memory layout are markedly different, and with any luck the OP will have a toolchain wise enough to prevent him from treating them as equals, because they're not. Outside of syntax sugar, they are entirely different beasts.

Comment: @Tower: Thanks, your suggestion helped me to get rid of the error: 'no match for operator...' However, the error 'y cannot appear in a constant expression' still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a c++ arrays?

Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<struct_name>>` ?

If you don't need dynamic allocation then you could use:

`std::array<std::array<struct_name, 2>, 3>` where 2 and 3 are the sizes of your 2D array.